# POST data to external API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, api, salesforce

I´m currently new into this whole API and JavaScript thing.

I need some help as i am googling this issue the whole day.

I am trying to link a html form and a JS button to salesforce via an API.

Everything is working and over a REST API checker everything works as it should.

Now my only problem is to get the Data passed on to the API.

I can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "https://eu12.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Case",true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer 00D1r000001nns1!ARcAQDuv... here the auth code");
      obj input = JSON.parse('{
      "Type": "Kundenvorgang",
      "Origin": "Email",
      "Status": "Offen",
      "Subject": "test",
      "Priority": "Niedrig",
      "SuppliedEmail": "blah@blah.com"
    }');
    xhttp.send(input);
    }
</script>
```

Honestly I don't know what i am doing wrong...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This is usually prohibited in browsers due to the same-origin policy, you need to do it from a server script. Notice that you have to disclose the authentication token, your users could then see it in the browser's Dev Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
var input = JSON.stringify({
      "Type": "Kundenvorgang",
      "Origin": "Email",
      "Status": "Offen",
      "Subject": "test",
      "Priority": "Niedrig",
      "SuppliedEmail": "blah@blah.com"
    });
    xhttp.send(input);
```

Hope this will help.